# Servicestack routing problems

Tags: servicestack

Hi i am new to servicestack 
have a problem, with the the routing 
i have mate a route

```
[Route("/Person/{ID}", "GET")]
public class GetPersonByID : IReturn<PersonResponse>
{
    public decimal ObjectId { get; set; }
}
[Route("/Organization/{ID}/Person", "GET")]
public class GetPersonByOrganizationId : List<PersonResponse>
{
    public decimal ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

but then i am trying `/Organization/281478302400588/Persons`, I am getting a error saying
`Unable to bind request`

> **Stacktrace:**  at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq,
>   IRestPath restPath) at
>   ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq,
>   IResponse httpRes, String operationName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to ensure that the segment name in the route matches a property in the DTO. So `{ID}` should be `{ObjectId}`
- In the second request, you should be using `IReturn<List<PersonResponse>>` rather than inheriting from `List<PersonResponse>` in your request

```cs
[Route("/Person/{ObjectId}", "GET")]
public class GetPersonByID : IReturn<PersonResponse>
{
    public decimal ObjectId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Organization/{ObjectId}/Person", "GET")]
public class GetPersonByOrganizationId : IReturn<List<PersonResponse>>
{
    public decimal ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

- You also note you are trying `/Organization/281478302400588/Persons` You have used `Persons` in the request, but the route is `Person` so either change the request or the route accordingly. (Probably best on the route. i.e. `[Route("/Organization/{ObjectId}/Persons", "GET")]`.

Then ensure in your service you are setting it up similar to this:

```cs
public class PersonService : Service
{
    public PersonResponse Get(GetPersonByID request)
    {
        // return new PersonResponse();
    }

    public List<PersonResponse> Get(GetPersonByOrganizationId request)
    {
        // return new List<PersonResponse>();
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.